# Multiple constructors when extending java class preference using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to take this Time Preference java class and convert it to Kotlin :

```
public TimePreference(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleAttr);
}
public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    // Do custom stuff here
    // ...
    // read attributes etc.
}
```

I am able to get the primary constructor but not the secondary constructors. I am getting a crash due to layout inflation errors when running.

```
class SpinnerPreference constructor(context: Context, attrs:  
AttributeSet, defStyleAttributes: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : 
Preference(context, attrs, defStyleAttributes, defStyleRes) {

}
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question and post the stack trace. Most likely, you are crashing due to the missing constructors. You can have secondary constructors in Kotlin using the `constructor` keyword: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html.

Answer (score 0):

From commonsware's comment checked the docs again a little more carfully this time and this seems to be working :).

```
class SpinnerPreference : Preference {

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttributes: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttributes, defStyleRes)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttributes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttributes)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

}
```